# Host Hugo website on github-pages

Tags: github-pages, hugo

I created a static website using Hugo and I don't know how to host it on github. The documentation on their website didn't help me.

After finishing my website, I created the public folder which contains in theory all the files needed for the website (whith this command : `hudo -t hyde-hyde`). When I open index.html with chrome I only see the content of my website without the theme. Is it normal ?

Then I moved all the files within the public folder into my gihub repo username.github.io/ , but I can't see any result (I can only see my previous commit which is a simple Hello World).

How should I porceed to generate correctly my website and host it on github ? Thanks.

Comment: Here is an article that explains how to set up a Hugo blog with GitHub pages: https://cjolowicz.github.io/posts/hosting-a-hugo-blog-on-github-pages-with-travis-ci/

Answer (score -2):

### How to create with HUGO

If you have a problem while creating your site, check this [tutorial](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/).

### How to Host HUGO website on GitHub (Pages)

Check this [LINK](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/) where it shows you **step by step** all the procedures to host *HUGO* on GitHub, on both *User/Organization Pages* and on *Project Pages*.

Check list:

> When I open index.html with chrome I only see the content of my website without the theme. Is it normal ?

- I know it might seem a little too obvious, but check the spelling. Sometimes you spend hours trying to find the error and it's just a typo, this case in the theme you wanted to.
- Have you tried another browser? It might not be the case, but checking it will get you out of doubt, also remember to delete the cache just in case.

> Then I moved all the files within the public folder into my gihub repo username.github.io/ , but I can't see any result (I can only see my previous commit which is a simple Hello World).

- Do you have a User/Organization Page (syntax: username.github.io) or a Project Page (syntax: username.github.io/project)?

**UPDATE 1:** Follow the instructions on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jt-J4Rc__M) for hosting on GitHub if unclear.

Could you add a link to your repo? Thanks.

Comment: As I said, it didn't help me. The tutorial is very unclear for a beginner.

Comment: @AhmedLahlouMimi There's no `hugo -t hyde-hyde`command there tho, so it may not be the same guide. Check "Update 1".